# check to see whether an object exists in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, boolean-expression

```py
a = {1 : 4}
print(4 in a)     # case 1: False

a = {1 : 's'}
print('s' in a)   # case 2: False

a = {1 : None}
print(None in a)  # case 3: False

a = {1: True}
print(True in a)  # case 4: True
```

so my question is why except the forth case all returns False ?

Comment: it searches on **keys** (of a dict)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest so why the forth case returns True while True key doesn't exist?

Comment: it does exist as `1 == True`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest   oh tnx u r right,I also checked this case and this proves your answer -->
a = {0 : 'foo'}
print(False in a)  # returns False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membership testing is done against dictionaries' "keys", not values. For values you can do:

```py
a = {1: 4}
print(4 in a.values())
```

But remember that it does a linear search as opposed to keys which is O(1).

For last case:

`bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True` is equal to `1`. (Their hashes are of course the same)

Basically the same effect as:

```py
s = {1, True}
print(len(s)) # 1
```

and

```py
a = {1: 10}
print(a[True]) # 10
```